# Trigger that changes opportunity stage upon task completion

Tags: trigger, tasks

I'm relatively new to triggers and I'm trying to develop one so that when a task is completed with a certain checkbox checked this automatically updates the related opportunity stage to a specific one.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Use Process Builder.

Comment: I am writing up step by step instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking at Process builder instead of a trigger.

**Step 1: Create a new process**
[image]

**Step 2: Choose an object, in your case it is task that has to update oppty.**

[image]

**Step 3: Add your criteria as a condition, I have set the condition as Task closed = true. You can do your own condition as per your design**

[image]

**Step 4: Select update record from Immediate actions and set stage on the oppty.**

[image]

**Step 5: Finally activate the process builder.**

Comment: Perfect!! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!! Just one final question. Since the opportunity stage is changed. Can this record update trigger a workflow rule?

Comment: That's a very valid question. I am not sure I can answer that, as per the docs, it clearly says to use either workflows or process builder, if you use both the order of execution is not predictable. Can you post this as a separate question?   : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_considerations_design.htm&language=en_US&type=0